# Command Line Backup and Restore Complete Graphics Configuration?

Tags: command-line, graphics, configuration

Is there some way of backing up and restoring the complete graphics configuration from the command line -- so that one doesn't get into a Catch-22 when a graphics configuration change doesn't work right?

Even when going through `Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers` to switch graphics driver, I frequently -- on various computers with various Ubuntu versions -- end up in a state where the graphics system doesn't work.  Once in this state, it frequently takes days to get the system back into working condition and a substantial amount of those cases requires reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: As long as you are using the ubuntu repositories you should be able to reverse these changes without having to reinstall. Other than that it is going to vary by machine and graphics card . Make note of which driver you used is about all you can do, you could save config files , /etc/xorg.conf

Comment: That hasn't been my experience.  There are configuration dependencies beyond xorg.conf and sometimes xorg.conf isn't even used.

Comment: If you have a problem you should ask a specific question. Anything installed from the repos should be fully and easily reversible, otherwise I would file a bug report.